# d3js v5 + Topojson v3 Show/Hide element on click legend

Tags: javascript, d3.js, topojson

I would like this reverse action http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/5d621a60e2d1d02086bf. When I click on an item of my legend, I want focus all elements of the map within these class.

**However, how isolate just one class compared to others?**

For example in this image, just show elements where the value is included between 23500 and 29000 and hide other elements.
[image]

I suggest to 1/ filter data and 2/ fill with the same color these elements but surely it's easier.
Here is my code : https://plnkr.co/edit/ga82Syjc8zxTdAxTVNXu?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/d3@5.0.0/dist/d3.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/topojson@3.0.0/dist/topojson.min.js"></script>
</head>

<svg class="carte_evolution">

<style>

</style>

<body>



<script>

let w = 600;
let h = 600;
let view = [0,0,600,600];

  //Dimension
  let svgCarteEvolution = d3.select(".carte_evolution")
      .attr("width", "100%")
      .attr("height", h)
      .attr("preserveAspectRatio","xMidYMid meet")
      .attr("viewBox", `${view[0]},${view[1]},${view[2]},${view[3]}`);

  //Map projection
  choro = d3.map();

  projection = d3.geoConicConformal()
      .center([1.282743, 46.328377])
      .scale(2600)
      .translate([w / 2, h / 2]);

  path = d3.geoPath()
      .projection(projection);




  //Load csv and topojson
  promises1 = d3.json("ze_WGS84_UTF8.topojson");
  promises2 = d3.csv("data.csv");

  Promise.all([promises1, promises2]).then(function(fr){


  //Join csv + topojson
  let featureCollection = topojson.feature(fr[0],fr[0].objects.ze_WGS84_UTF8)

  for (var i=0; i< fr[1].length;i++){
    var csvId = fr[1][i].codgeo;
    var csvValue0 = parseFloat(fr[1][i].value0);
    var csvYear0 = fr[1][i].year0;
    for (var j=0; j<featureCollection.features.length;j++){
      var jsonId = featureCollection.features[j].properties.codgeo;
      if (csvId === jsonId) {
        featureCollection.features[j].properties.value0 = csvValue0;
        featureCollection.features[j].properties.year0 = csvYear0;
        break;
      }
    }
  }


  let color = d3.scaleQuantile()
      .range(["#d1e0c9","#b3cea8","#8fb983","#539f53","#008d36"]);

  color.domain([
        12000,17500,19500,21500,23500,29000
      ]);

  //Map
  svgCarteEvolution.append("g")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(featureCollection.features)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", "dep")
    .attr("d", path)
    .style("fill", function(d){
      var value = d.properties["value0"];
      return value? color(value):"#ccc";
    });


  //legend
  let legend = svgCarteEvolution.selectAll("g.legend_entree")
    .data(color.range().reverse())
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class","legend_entree");

    legend
      .append('rect')
      .attr("x", 30)
      .attr("y", function(d, i) {
         return 65 + i * 20;
      })
     .attr("width", 20)
     .attr("height", 10)
     .style("stroke", "black")
     .style("stroke-width", 0.1)
     .style("fill", function(d){return d;});
         //the data objects are the fill colors

    legend
        .append('text')
        .attr("x", 55) //leave 5 pixel space after the <rect>
        .attr("y", function(d, i) {
           return 65 + i * 20;
        })
        .attr("dy", "0.8em") //place text one line *below* the x,y point
        .style("font-family","latomedium")
        .style("font-size","0.9em")
        .text(function(d,i) {
            var extent = color.invertExtent(d);
            //extent will be a two-element array, format it however you want:
            var format = d3.format("");
            return `${format(+extent[0])} - ${format(+extent[1])}`
          });

  });

  </script>

</body>
  </html>
```

**data.csv**

```
"codgeo","year0","value0","year1","value1"
"0050",2012,19162,2014,19698.8
"0051",2012,18501.125,2014,19125.5
"0052",2012,18684.6666666667,2014,19454
"0053",2012,19826,2014,20573.9
"0054",2012,18881.1111111111,2014,19513
"0055",2012,17942.5,2014,18657.3
"0056",2012,19299.0476190476,2014,19703.9
"0057",2012,18873.8095238095,2014,19539.3
"0059",2012,18199,2014,18719
"0060",2012,18921,2014,19563.2
"0061",2012,21259.5238095238,2014,21748.3
"0101",2012,,2014,
"0102",2012,,2014,
"0103",2012,,2014,
"0106",2012,,2014,
"0201",2012,,2014,17250
"0202",2012,,2014,17246.7
"0203",2012,,2014,14972
"0204",2012,,2014,14612.6
"0205",2012,,2014,15617.3
"0206",2012,,2014,13369
"0301",2012,,2014,
"0302",2012,,2014,
"0303",2012,,2014,
"0401",2012,,2014,12522.3
"0402",2012,,2014,15483.8
"0403",2012,,2014,14344.6
"0404",2012,,2014,13134
"0601",2012,,2014,
"1101",2012,23144.7619047619,2014,23464
"1102",2012,22223.5,2014,22729.1
"1103",2012,20637.2222222222,2014,21088
"1104",2012,20402,2014,20901
"1105",2012,21782.7777777778,2014,22274.4
"1106",2012,18304.375,2014,18918
"1107",2012,20038.6666666667,2014,20406.5
"1108",2012,19493,2014,19936.5
"1109",2012,28156.8901098901,2014,28660
"1110",2012,20294.8,2014,20639.5
"1111",2012,22490.6666666667,2014,22812.4
"1112",2012,25996.6666666667,2014,26503.5
"1113",2012,25301.7391304348,2014,25639.6
"1114",2012,21184,2014,21611.9
"1115",2012,20586,2014,20954
"1116",2012,25449.5,2014,25742.4
"1117",2012,22279.3333333333,2014,22665
"1118",2012,19040,2014,19307.2
"1119",2012,22059.0909090909,2014,22519
"2101",2012,17416,2014,18133.9
"2102",2012,18721,2014,19275.4
"2103",2012,19554.7826086957,2014,20204
"2104",2012,20352.8571428571,2014,20892.8
"2105",2012,19630.5555555556,2014,20157.6
"2106",2012,18689,2014,19445.2
"2107",2012,17676.6666666667,2014,18309.1
"2201",2012,19209.5238095238,2014,19791
"2202",2012,17090,2014,17820
"2203",2012,16258.6666666667,2014,17014
"2204",2012,17987.619047619,2014,18675.2
"2205",2012,17320.8333333333,2014,18056
"2206",2012,18163.2,2014,18851
"2207",2012,19732.1428571429,2014,20284.7
"2208",2012,19973.3333333333,2014,20690
"2209",2012,17625,2014,18402
"2210",2012,18778.0952380952,2014,19447.6
"2211",2012,17420,2014,18158.8
"2301",2012,18978.8461538462,2014,19609.3
"2302",2012,19920,2014,20419
"2303",2012,18947,2014,19704.7
"2304",2012,20011.7391304348,2014,20639
"2305",2012,18633.4166666667,2014,19348.6
"2306",2012,19222.6666666667,2014,19937.6
"2307",2012,19716,2014,20349.3
"2401",2012,19496,2014,20116.7
"2402",2012,17587.3913043478,2014,18264.3
"2403",2012,18039.3333333333,2014,18668.9
"2404",2012,20862,2014,21386.8
"2405",2012,19088,2014,19617.5
"2406",2012,19682,2014,20246
"2407",2012,17765,2014,18244
"2408",2012,18813.3333333333,2014,19590.5
"2409",2012,18460.8695652174,2014,19134
"2410",2012,19341.3333333333,2014,20286.2
"2411",2012,18503.5,2014,19170
"2412",2012,20074.7619047619,2014,20669
"2413",2012,19886,2014,20426.5
"2414",2012,18549,2014,19111.7
"2415",2012,19298.0952380952,2014,19929
"2416",2012,19159.5833333333,2014,19763.3
"2417",2012,19013.3333333333,2014,19521.9
"2418",2012,20852,2014,21314
"2419",2012,19696.8,2014,20135.4
"2501",2012,18832.9166666667,2014,19616.7
"2502",2012,19839.6428571429,2014,20447.3
"2503",2012,19357,2014,19949.3
"2504",2012,17890,2014,18668.5
"2505",2012,17836.1904761905,2014,18619.5
"2506",2012,18373.0434782609,2014,19247.3
"2507",2012,18855,2014,19788.7
"2508",2012,18192.0833333333,2014,19076
"2509",2012,19105,2014,19896.6
"2510",2012,18837.2222222222,2014,19621.4
"2511",2012,18071.5,2014,18835
"2512",2012,18059.5,2014,18796.7
"2513",2012,17989.5652173913,2014,18533.5
"2601",2012,20356,2014,21106.7
"2602",2012,18218.4,2014,18926.7
"2603",2012,20719.6666666667,2014,21264.4
"2604",2012,18828.3333333333,2014,19445.7
"2605",2012,17496,2014,18232
"2606",2012,18618.3333333333,2014,19419.2
"2607",2012,18150,2014,18717
"2608",2012,19290,2014,20024
"2609",2012,18376,2014,19020
"2610",2012,18123.5,2014,18997.2
"2611",2012,18232,2014,19093.1
"2612",2012,19023.3962264151,2014,19581.7
"2613",2012,18402.2222222222,2014,19055
"2614",2012,19352.6666666667,2014,19970
"3110",2012,17632,2014,18171.3
"3111",2012,19872.3214285714,2014,20498.6
"3112",2012,17909.5,2014,18786
"3113",2012,19370.8695652174,2014,20029
"3114",2012,17411.6666666667,2014,18153.1
"3115",2012,16527.5,2014,17161.7
"3116",2012,17494,2014,18124.5
"3117",2012,16522.5,2014,17252.5
"3121",2012,18958.5714285714,2014,19749.5
"3122",2012,15848,2014,16471.3
"3123",2012,17325,2014,18070
"3124",2012,17319,2014,18080.7
"3125",2012,16943,2014,17776.5
"3126",2012,17054,2014,17783.8
"3127",2012,17860.6666666667,2014,18527.8
"4101",2012,19057,2014,20396.5
"4102",2012,18167.3913043478,2014,18923.8
"4103",2012,20100,2014,20734.3
"4104",2012,19253.4615384615,2014,19914.7
"4105",2012,18178,2014,18899.6
"4106",2012,18415.5555555556,2014,19180
"4107",2012,19765.3333333333,2014,20611.4
"4108",2012,17936.3043478261,2014,18670.5
"4109",2012,19220,2014,19884
"4110",2012,19699,2014,20456
"4111",2012,19975.5555555556,2014,21490
"4112",2012,18561.9047619048,2014,19239.6
"4113",2012,18533,2014,19207
"4114",2012,17932,2014,18625
"4115",2012,18513.6,2014,19304
"4201",2012,21662,2014,22259.4
"4202",2012,22121.4285714286,2014,22678
"4203",2012,20694.9743589744,2014,21249.2
"4204",2012,20996.6666666667,2014,21554
"4205",2012,20637.2,2014,20939.5
"4206",2012,22284.4,2014,22998
"4207",2012,21402,2014,21892
"4208",2012,20530.4761904762,2014,20987.7
"4209",2012,27116,2014,27578
"4301",2012,19866.7857142857,2014,20474.7
"4302",2012,19037.6923076923,2014,19688.7
"4303",2012,26342.380952381,2014,26900.4
"4304",2012,23223.3333333333,2014,24219
"4305",2012,19166.4516129032,2014,19840
"4306",2012,19092.2222222222,2014,19879.5
"4307",2012,20652,2014,21500.8
"4308",2012,18128,2014,18743
"4309",2012,18185,2014,18844.7
"5201",2012,18881.4814814815,2014,19667.6
"5202",2012,17665.6,2014,18286
"5203",2012,20616,2014,21241
"5204",2012,19844.8,2014,20508
"5205",2012,19443,2014,20094.4
"5206",2012,18905.7142857143,2014,19605
"5207",2012,17964.6666666667,2014,18666
"5208",2012,18107.3333333333,2014,18734.4
"5209",2012,18951.7857142857,2014,19703.8
"5210",2012,18635.7142857143,2014,19332
"5211",2012,18973.2258064516,2014,19556.5
"5212",2012,18178.6666666667,2014,18824
"5213",2012,19304.6666666667,2014,19966.7
"5214",2012,18363.3333333333,2014,19098.9
"5215",2012,19146.6666666667,2014,19786.7
"5216",2012,18103.3333333333,2014,18876.7
"5217",2012,18984,2014,19686
"5218",2012,19186.1904761905,2014,19813.8
"5219",2012,20042.380952381,2014,20712.9
"5301",2012,19939.2,2014,20655.3
"5302",2012,18221.4285714286,2014,18960
"5303",2012,20016,2014,20691.3
"5304",2012,18641.5,2014,19282.2
"5305",2012,19581.3333333333,2014,20232.9
"5306",2012,19916.0869565217,2014,20649.4
"5307",2012,17941.3333333333,2014,18671
"5308",2012,19373.3333333333,2014,19991.9
"5309",2012,19634.347826087,2014,20377.6
"5310",2012,18645.3846153846,2014,19283.8
"5311",2012,18720,2014,19397.2
"5312",2012,20578,2014,21143.8
"5313",2012,19380.6666666667,2014,20159.3
"5314",2012,19439,2014,20248.1
"5315",2012,19573,2014,20304.3
"5316",2012,18751.25,2014,19417.2
"5317",2012,18940,2014,19701.3
"5318",2012,20075.4166666667,2014,20740
"5401",2012,17907.5,2014,18522.9
"5402",2012,18704.6666666667,2014,19349
"5403",2012,18580.3846153846,2014,19280
"5404",2012,17407,2014,18222
"5405",2012,19327.5,2014,20055.3
"5406",2012,18512.4,2014,19128
"5407",2012,19217.6,2014,19903.5
"5408",2012,18673,2014,19379.3
"5409",2012,20270,2014,20855.6
"5410",2012,19489.1666666667,2014,20238.1
"5411",2012,17890,2014,18620.5
"5412",2012,18078.0952380952,2014,18834
"5413",2012,19446.5,2014,20043
"7201",2012,18008.4637681159,2014,18697.3
"7202",2012,18425,2014,19159
"7203",2012,18106.6666666667,2014,18658.7
"7204",2012,20667,2014,21249.5
"7205",2012,18035.3333333333,2014,18711.3
"7206",2012,18450.9523809524,2014,19101.3
"7207",2012,20320.8695652174,2014,20948
"7208",2012,19536,2014,20100
"7209",2012,18869.3333333333,2014,19480.7
"7210",2012,17737.5,2014,18362
"7211",2012,17410,2014,17987.6
"7212",2012,20164.6666666667,2014,20683.9
"7213",2012,19245,2014,19834
"7214",2012,20302,2014,20867.6
"7301",2012,18256,2014,18876.3
"7302",2012,17957,2014,18514
"7303",2012,18034.6666666667,2014,18724.8
"7304",2012,19017.2222222222,2014,19799.3
"7305",2012,17916.1904761905,2014,18698
"7306",2012,18578,2014,19336.7
"7307",2012,18857.619047619,2014,19230
"7308",2012,18793.3333333333,2014,19457.6
"7309",2012,19058.6956521739,2014,19787.6
"7310",2012,18895.3333333333,2014,19429.5
"7311",2012,18878.1780538302,2014,19430.7
"7312",2012,18183.8461538462,2014,18879.2
"7313",2012,18197.3333333333,2014,18632
"7401",2012,19040,2014,19716
"7402",2012,18143.3333333333,2014,18897.2
"7403",2012,17301.3043478261,2014,17984
"7404",2012,19118,2014,19698
"8201",2012,20643.8095238095,2014,21227.1
"8202",2012,20174.6666666667,2014,20682.4
"8203",2012,18474.4444444444,2014,19119.6
"8204",2012,18964.6153846154,2014,19694
"8205",2012,17833.8461538462,2014,18486
"8206",2012,18796,2014,19433
"8207",2012,18750.4347826087,2014,19414.5
"8208",2012,19158.8,2014,19833.1
"8209",2012,20058.9655172414,2014,20741.1
"8210",2012,21119.1153846154,2014,21684.5
"8211",2012,19926,2014,20499.3
"8212",2012,18585.7142857143,2014,19272
"8213",2012,21155,2014,21768
"8214",2012,20965,2014,21470
"8215",2012,20356.9230769231,2014,20849.2
"8216",2012,21009.6,2014,21576.5
"8217",2012,20380.7692307692,2014,20996
"8218",2012,23005.2173913043,2014,23712.7
"8219",2012,27201.9230769231,2014,27749.3
"8220",2012,21017,2014,21626.5
"8221",2012,21245.0909090909,2014,21706.7
"8222",2012,23036.0869565217,2014,23862.9
"8301",2012,18453.9393939394,2014,19023.3
"8302",2012,18534.3333333333,2014,19190
"8303",2012,18492,2014,19091.3
"8304",2012,18855.7142857143,2014,19606.7
"8305",2012,17307.5595238095,2014,18159
"8306",2012,17459.1666666667,2014,18457
"8307",2012,17890.4761904762,2014,18484.8
"8308",2012,18963,2014,19466.1
"8309",2012,18347.1428571429,2014,19084
"8310",2012,20412,2014,21071.7
"8311",2012,19008.5,2014,19795.7
"8312",2012,18111.6666666667,2014,18856.5
"9101",2012,17408.5714285714,2014,17945.3
"9102",2012,16617.3333333333,2014,17173
"9103",2012,17123.3333333333,2014,17661
"9104",2012,16840,2014,17349.6
"9105",2012,18586,2014,19386.7
"9106",2012,18106.6666666667,2014,18625
"9107",2012,17128.4615384615,2014,17763
"9108",2012,16940.8695652174,2014,17503.5
"9109",2012,17352,2014,17867.5
"9110",2012,16858,2014,17391.3
"9111",2012,19566.6666666667,2014,20024.4
"9112",2012,17690.4,2014,18320.7
"9113",2012,18336.5217391304,2014,19110
"9114",2012,18100.4545454545,2014,18640.7
"9115",2012,17447.2222222222,2014,17903.9
"9116",2012,17108,2014,17654.6
"9301",2012,18502,2014,19034.2
"9302",2012,18934.8,2014,19401.5
"9303",2012,18952.3076923077,2014,19365.3
"9304",2012,18794.7619047619,2014,19335
"9305",2012,20466.1111111111,2014,20830.8
"9306",2012,20292.8,2014,20668.7
"9307",2012,19959,2014,20333.3
"9308",2012,21603.3333333333,2014,22211.1
"9309",2012,18084,2014,18679.5
"9310",2012,19009,2014,19507
"9311",2012,19514.6666666667,2014,20090
"9312",2012,19813.6,2014,20490.6
"9313",2012,18840,2014,19254.8
"9314",2012,19946.0357142857,2014,20238
"9315",2012,19492,2014,20070.5
"9316",2012,17739.1304347826,2014,18245.7
"9317",2012,17904,2014,18510.6
"9401",2012,19633.8461538462,2014,20418.3
"9402",2012,17570,2014,17890
"9403",2012,17200.8333333333,2014,17640.5
"9404",2012,17777.2666666667,2014,18376.4
"9405",2012,17254.5,2014,17473.5
"9406",2012,17553.3333333333,2014,18426
"9407",2012,16885,2014,17577.7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your instincts will work - filter the path data according to the color:

```
features.filter(function(feature) {
   return color(feature.properties["value0"]) == d;
})
```

*I saved your feature paths in the variable features in the plunkrs below*

As the datum of each legend entry is a color, we can just filter the paths based on which datum would produce the same color when scaled. We could alternatively give class names or apply other indicators to filter.

---

Color the filtered paths on the event, revert all paths on some sort anti-event. Since you haven't said what will reset the map, I'll assume if you click on the same legend entry twice in a row the map should reset (this lets you toggle between each legend entry). To do so we'll need to keep track of which legend entry is currently in focus:

```
var highlighted = "";
```

Then we just listen for a click event on the legend entry and:

```
.on("click",function(d,i) {
       highlighted = ""; //reset

       // revert map back to default state           
     }
     else {
       highlighted = d;

      // filter features to highlight certain ones.
 })
```

Altogether that might look like:

```
.on("click",function(d,i) {
     // clicking an active entry: reset:
     if(highlighted == d) {

      // reset opacity on each path:
      features.style("opacity",1);

      // reset legend entries' fills:
      legend.selectAll("rect")
       .style("fill",function(d) { return d; });

      // reset highlight variable since nothing is highlighted
       highlighted = ""; 

     }
     // clicking a different entry: highlight that entry:
     else {
       //update highlighted variable
       highlighted = d;

       // set opacity low for all features, filter for chosen features and style accordingly:
       features.style("opacity",0.2)
        .filter(function(f) {
         return color(f.properties["value0"]) == d;
        })
        .style("opacity",1);

      // hollow legend entries
      legend.selectAll("rect")
       .style("fill","white")

      // fill selected option:
      d3.select(this).select("rect")
        .style("fill",function(d) { return d;});
     }
 })
```

Which looks something like:

[image]

*(I'm formatting the legend entries to show what is highlighted - I changed your stroke to accomodate this)*

Here's an updated [plunkr](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/qOHd2ZIYuFvj6Yk1).

*If you want to be able to toggle multiple legend items at once, then the logic gets a bit more detailed and the highlighted variable becomes an array*

As an alternative with mouseover/off events rather than clicks (so no need to track what is actively shown), here's a slightly different approach using the same principles: [plunkr](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/RnUaI1A73v6m5U1a)